# How to unlock / unload file that Powershell created?

Tags: powershell

I'm using a scriptlet to create a file from a SQL query then email it to myself. I'd like to delete the file once it's done being emailed but it stays locked by Powershell until the script is done so it errors out. How do I unlock/unload the file it creates and delete it in the same script? I'm sure there's a way! :)

```
#Connection Strings
$Database = "somedb"
$Server = "localhost"
#SMTP Relay Server
$SMTPServer = "172.16.150.10"
#Export File
$AttachmentPath = "e:\folder\filename.csv"
# Connect to SQL and query data, extract data to SQL Adapter
$SqlQuery = "select * from some.where"
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$Server;Initial Catalog=$Database;Integrated Security = True"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$nRecs = $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$nRecs | Out-Null
#Populate Hash Table
$objTable = $DataSet.Tables[0]
#Export Hash Table to CSV File
$objTable | Export-CSV $AttachmentPath
#Send SMTP Message
$Mailer = new-object Net.Mail.SMTPclient($SMTPServer)
$From = "me@domain.org"
$To = "me@domain.org"
$Subject = "Report csv"
$Body = "Here is the data for the last month!"
$Msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage($From,$To,$Subject,$Body)
$Msg.IsBodyHTML = $False
$Attachment = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($AttachmentPath)
$Msg.attachments.add($Attachment)
$Mailer.send($Msg)

#THIS COMMAND IS NOT ABLE TO DELETE
Remove-Item $AttachmentPath
```

Just looking to figure out how to unload/unlock the file it made so I can delete it once it's been emailed, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, this worked great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by **@PetSerAl**, you can use the [`Dispose()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w54a951%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method of the `$Msg` ([`MailMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) object to release all resources used by it:

```
$Msg.Dispose()
```